# Incrementing a counter with variable speed

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm in the process of creating an incremental game in JavaScript (like CookieClicker, if you've ever played it).

To use CookieClicker as an example, you generate a certain number of cookies every second. If you're making 700 cookies per second, the counter increments by 1 cookie 700 times a second (or appears to).

Currently in my game, if you are making 700 "cookies" per second, the counter will increment by 700 "cookies" once per second, rather than increasing smoothly by a fixed amount.

I'm at a loss on how to do this. I've made a function that calculates the number of "cookies" you make per second, and I tried using that number to make the time parameter of `window.setInterval()` a variable, but I'm not even sure if that's possible let alone practical.

I'm pretty sure this isn't the right approach but I'll post the relevant code anyway:

```
function getManaPerSecond(){
    manaPerSecond = earthEssence + (windEssence * 5) + (waterEssence * 10) + 
    (fireEssence * 150);
};

window.setInterval(function(){
    getManaPerSecond();
}, 1000);

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(manaPerSecond>0){
        incrementalMana++;
     document.getElementById('incrementalMana').innerHTML = incrementalMana;
 }
 }, (1000/manaPerSecond));
```

Comment: I have made something similar like this before, and what I decided on was, on average you should have 60 frames per second, so I updated the counter 60 times per second. This is not nessecerialy 100% correct, but it will give the impression of a "smooth flow". You might have to use double precision numbers to get the desired result. As a rule of thumb, 60 times per second is roughly once per 17 ms (16.66666...). You would of course have to do `var incrementBy = manaPerSecond / 60; manascore += incrementBy`. You should not add 1, as it seems like you do here, but add X, the desired amount.

Comment: you can look into `requestAnimationFrame` for a bit smoother animations https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the frequency changes, you need to stop the old interval function and start a new one.

```
var manaCounter;
var oldManaPerSecond = 0;
function restartManaCounter(manaPerSecond) {
    if (manaPerSecond != oldManaPerSecond) {
        clearInterval(manaCounter);
        oldManaPerSecond = manaPerSecond;
        if (manaPerSecond > 0) {
            manaCounter = setInterval(function() {
                incrementalMana++;
                document.getElementById('incrementalMana').innerHTML = incrementalMana;
            }, 1000/manaPerSecond);
        }
    }
}

function getManaPerSecond(){
    var manaPerSecond = earthEssence + (windEssence * 5) + (waterEssence * 10) +  (fireEssence * 150);
    return manaPerSecond;
};

window.setInterval(function() {
    restartManaCounter(getManaPerSecond());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hmm, something about this isn't right. Whenever I restart my game and buy a single building (that generates 1 mana per second) the counter goes from 1, to 3, to 6, to 10, etc. (in other words, +1, +2, +3, +4, +5) rather than increasing by 1 at a dynamic speed.

Comment: Sorry, the code to call `setInterval` should be inside the first `if`.